# How to make Web Server B only accessible by Web Server A

Tags: ajax, server, webserver, http-post, ws-security

### Explanation

I need to post form data from server **A** To **B** using **AJAX** to store the data on a database but I don't know how to achieve this **securely** to prevent cross site forgery attack.

#### Question

How Do I do it? Is it possible to access server **B** only by server **A**?

Comment: Which httpserver do you use? Apache has a module `mod_authz_host` that has the ability to allow only certain ip-adresses. So you could have a rule like this `Require ip ip-adress-of-server-A` .

Comment: Server A is Apache and B is YAWS, Do you think this is the safest way?

Comment: Safest way would be to use iptables or hosts.allow/deny if your servers are runing on a unix-system. The apache module is platform independent. But beware to use #-comments in the configuration because this may make your server vulnerable [https://vigilance.fr/vulnerability/Apache-httpd-rules-added-by-mod-access-compat-or-mod-authz-host-16636](https://vigilance.fr/vulnerability/Apache-httpd-rules-added-by-mod-access-compat-or-mod-authz-host-16636).

Comment: Thanks, Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark and vote it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safest way would be to use iptables or hosts.allow/deny if your servers are runing on a unix-system. The apache module is platform independent. But beware to use #-comments in the configuration because this may make your server vulnerable [https://vigilance.fr/vulnerability/Apache-httpd-rules-added-by-mod-access-compa‌​t-or-mod-authz-host-16636](https://vigilance.fr/vulnerability/Apache-httpd-rules-added-by-mod-access-compa%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bt-or-mod-authz-host-16636)